# Both @Component and @Named for the same bean class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

Does a class which will act as a bean in a Spring application require both `@Component` and `@Named` at the same time?

What is the significance if both are used so?

I tried searching the net as well as saw the standard documentation of these annotations and found them a bit confusing.

Finally which name is taken by the application if the `@Named` annotation does not specify any name for the bean?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`@Component` and `@Named` are annotations that basically do the same thing, but come from different APIs.

`@Component` belongs to Spring API. It marks class to be autodetected as a bean and optionally allows you to specify a name for that bean (`@Component("foo")`). Without explicit name specification detected bean will get a default name derived from the name of its class.

`@Named` belongs to `javax.inject` API. It marks class to be autodetected as a bean and requires you to specify a name.

Spring supports both these APIs. It doesn't make sense to use both annotations at the same class since they provide the same functionality.

**See also:**

- [3.10 Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)

Comment: Worth noting. There are various libraries etc that work with spring that work differently with '@Named' vs '@Component'.

Answer (score 13):

Spring supports `@Named` annotation (JSR-330) as an alternative to `@Component` (Spring).

Generally, `@Named` is poorly named since doesn't describe what it does, so I would prefer to use `@Component` whenever I can.

Comment: Agreed, (a)Named is poorly named. However, many classes are a shared resource amongst projects from different frameworks. Using @Named to bean-ify the class requires javax.injection as a dependency for each application, much better than another framework depending on Spring for the annotation..

Answer (score 0):

Either of the both should be used.
Using both @Component and @Named don't make any sense.
Adding to above (Other's) comment @Component("[someComponentID]") and @Named("[someNamedID]") to assign an ID to a bean by passing the ID in the parenthesis, if not implicitly assigned one.